# XML::Twig gives me tags when I don't want them while selectively printing xml elements in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm having the strangest behaviour from XML::Twig which I cannot understand.

I have an XML that looks like the following (but is much, much bigger, around 500 MB)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
<header creationtool="MemoQ" creationtoolversion="6.2.21" segtype="sentence" adminlang="en-us" creationid="" srclang="pt-pt" o-tmf="MemoQTM" datatype="unknown">
 <prop type="defclient"> </prop>
 <prop type="defproject"> </prop>
 <prop type="defdomain"> </prop>
 <prop type="defsubject"> </prop>
 <prop type="description"> </prop>
 <prop type="targetlang">it</prop>
 <prop type="name">pt_PT-it_IT</prop>
</header>
<body>

  <tu changedate="20120625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
      <prop type="x-context-pre">&lt;seg&gt;O recinto do Pavilhão Atlântico, versátil por natureza, está vocacionado para receber os mais variados eventos.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;A Sala Atlântico, com uma arena de 5 200 m2, abriga, com uma versatilidade única, todo o tipo de eventos.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="it">
      <seg>È composto da tre aree fra di esse integrate, le quali sono tutte facilmente adattabili alle caratteristiche specifiche di ogni evento.</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>


 <tu changedate="20130625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
      <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <seg>O recinto do Pavilhão Atlântico, versátil por natureza, está vocacionado para receber os mais variados eventos.</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="it">
      <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>


   <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
      <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="it">
      <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
     <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
      <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <seg>Teste</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="it">
      <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
   <tu changedate="20110625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
      <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
      <seg>Teste</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="it">
      <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

And the following code that passes twice through the document: first it makes a hash that associates each "seg" to the most recent "changedate" attribute, then it scrolls the document, only printing the "tu"'s which are the most recent (have not a smaller "changedate" than the hashed one). Here's the code:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $filename = 'pt_PT-it_IT-novo2.tmx';
my $out_filename = 'out.tmx';
open my $out, '>', $out_filename;
binmode $out, ':encoding(UTF-8)';


print "PASSAGE 1...\n";

my $first_pass = new XML::Twig (twig_handlers => {tu => \&first_pass});
$first_pass->parsefile($filename);
$first_pass->purge();
print "DONE\n";


print "\nPASSAGE 2....\n";
my $second_pass = new XML::Twig (#twig_roots => { 'tu' => 1 },
                #twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
            pretty_print => 'indented',
            twig_handlers => {tu => \&second_pass});
$second_pass->parsefile($filename);

close $out;
print "\nDONE\n";

{my %hash;
sub first_pass {
    my($twig, $tu) = @_;
    my $seg = $tu->first_child('tuv')->first_child('seg')->text;
    my $changedate = $tu->att('changedate');
    if (
    (!(exists($hash{$seg})) )
        || (($hash{$seg}) lt $changedate)
    ) {
        $hash{$seg} = $changedate;
    }
    $twig->purge();
}   



sub second_pass {
    my($twig, $tu) = @_;
    #print $original_tu->text;
    my $seg = $tu->first_child('tuv')->first_child('seg')->text;

    my $changedate = $tu->att('changedate');
    #$changedate = substr $changedate, 0, 8;
    #my $hash = md5($seg);
    if (!(($hash{$seg}) eq $changedate)) {
            print "================================\n";
                print "NOT PRINTED\n";
                print $seg;
                print "\n BECAUSE DATE: ";
            print $changedate;
            print " IS OLDER THAN FOUND IN PASS ONE: ";
            print $hash{$seg};
            print "\n=================================\n";
            $twig->purge;   

        }
else {
    $twig->print($out);
    $twig->purge;
}
#$twig->flush($out);
}
}
```

The result I get when running the above code on the above example is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <body>
    <tu changedate="20130625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>O recinto do Pavilhão Atlântico, versátil por natureza, está vocacionado para receber os mais variados eventos.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <body>
    <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <body>
    <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>Teste</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
 </body>
</tmx>
```

As you can see, I get the enclosing brackets of "tu" tag after each deleted "tu" ("body" and "tmx") aswell as the opening brackets of the whole xml document.

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Thanks a lot for any help, however small it may be!

Edit:
Optionally, I tried doing

```
if (!(($hash{$seg}) eq $changedate)) {
        print "================================\n";
            print "APAGADO\n";
            print $seg;
            print "\n POIS DATA DE ORIGINAL: ";
            print $changedate;
            print " E MAIS ANTIGA QUE ENCONTRADA: ";
            print $hash{$seg};
            print "\n=================================\n";
            $tu->delete;
}
$twig->flush($out);
```

But then I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header adminlang="en-us" creationid="" creationtool="MemoQ" creationtoolversion="6.2.21" datatype="unknown" o-tmf="MemoQTM" segtype="sentence" srclang="pt-pt">
    <prop type="defclient"> </prop>
    <prop type="defproject"> </prop>
    <prop type="defdomain"> </prop>
    <prop type="defsubject"> </prop>
    <prop type="description"> </prop>
    <prop type="targetlang">it</prop>
    <prop type="name">pt_PT-it_IT</prop>
  </header>
  <body></body>
</tmx>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header adminlang="en-us" creationid="" creationtool="MemoQ" creationtoolversion="6.2.21" datatype="unknown" o-tmf="MemoQTM" segtype="sentence" srclang="pt-pt">
    <prop type="defclient"> </prop>
    <prop type="defproject"> </prop>
    <prop type="defdomain"> </prop>
    <prop type="defsubject"> </prop>
    <prop type="description"> </prop>
    <prop type="targetlang">it</prop>
    <prop type="name">pt_PT-it_IT</prop>
  </header>
  <body>
    <tu changedate="20130625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>O recinto do Pavilhão Atlântico, versátil por natureza, está vocacionado para receber os mais variados eventos.</seg>
      </tuv>
       <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu changedate="20140625T175037Z" changeid="ana">
      <prop type="client"> </prop>
      <prop type="project"> </prop>
      <prop type="domain"> </prop>
      <prop type="subject"> </prop>
      <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
      <prop type="aligned">yes</prop>
      <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
        <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg>Composto por três áreas integradas, todos os espaços são facilmente adaptados às características de cada evento.&lt;/seg></prop>
        <seg>Teste</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="it">
        <seg>Lo spazio di pertinenza del Pavilhão Atlântico, versatile per natura, è adatto a ricevere gli eventi più svariati.</seg>
      </tuv>
     </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>

  </body>
</tmx>
```

Which has a lot of "body" tags in the middle aswell as "header" ones.
That's why I decided to try the "print only the most recent" strategy.

Thanks again
Dasen

Comment: [Crossposted](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1048534).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the whole twig to be printed, do not print it. Print only the relevant part:

```
# $twig->print($out); # Prints everything.
$tu->print($out);
```

Comment: God, that worked, but how do I print out the necessary begining and end tags of the whole document?

Comment: @dasen: The traditional way is to `->delete` unwanted elements and print what remains.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I changed my question to address that strategy which I tried to use before the current one, and as you can see it still gives me enclosing tags where there should be none. Thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second pass handler should either delete the `tu` if it's not used, or flush the twig otherwise:

```
sub second_pass {
    my($twig, $tu) = @_;
    #print $original_tu->text;
    my $seg = $tu->first_child('tuv')->first_child('seg')->text;

    my $changedate = $tu->att('changedate');
    #$changedate = substr $changedate, 0, 8;
    #my $hash = md5($seg);
    if (!(($hash{$seg}) eq $changedate)) {
            print "================================\n";
                print "NOT PRINTED\n";
                print $seg;
                print "\n BECAUSE DATE: ";
            print $changedate;
            print " IS OLDER THAN FOUND IN PASS ONE: ";
            print $hash{$seg};
            print "\n=================================\n";
            $tu->delete;   

        }
else {
    $t->flush($out);
}

}
```

Flushing the end of the twig should happen automagically at the end of the parse.

Sorry, I hadn't seen you edit. I think what happens is that mixing delete on the current element and flush created a bit of a confusion in the module's code. See if flushing conditionaly improves things.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "flushing conditionaly"?

Comment: I've solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The problem I was flushing the twig instead of just the tu, I did "else { $tu->flush($out)" and now it doesn't print the closing "body" or "tmx" tags!

Comment: Are you sure? When you flush the element, internally that gets converted into a call to flush the tree up to the element. So both ways should be equivalent. I have to check what's going on exactly, but deleting the element currently being parsed is a little bit tricky, the parent element has to become the current element. So flushing the twig right after deleting the element may creates some confusion. Anyway, your problem is solved. Good.